# android lollipop notification icon

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I would like to know how and where can I design android notification icon for my app for android Lollipop and above. I read the google guidelines for the same but couldn't find a good tutorial for designing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a notifications icons is to use:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

and than put it to your project.

This article might be also helpful:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

If you would have any question, please feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

1.**To design notification icon**

[Android Assets-Notification Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html)

Icon generators allow you to quickly and easily generate icons from existing source images, clipart, or text.

2.**To develop Android notification**
Best tutorial which I used to develop easily. Clear explanation.
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/notifications/android-notifications-example/

3.**To develop Cloud push Notification**

“**Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)** is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices”

GCM tutorial available in this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

Happy coding :)